# Possible to filter user stories on name starts with?

Tags: extjs, rally

Is it possible to filter user stories on their name? For example: 
`filters: [{properrty: 'Name', operator: 'startsWith', value: 'EPIC'}]`

I am using the 2.0p5 rally sdk.
Also is there a documentation where I can look at for the App sdk? That explains querying on different attributes?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a startsWith operator, but you can use contains:

```
filters: [{property: 'Name', operator: 'contains', value: 'EPIC'}]
```

All possible values for filter operators can be found here:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.QueryFilter-cfg-operator

You can then use the [filterBy](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy) method to further narrow down the result set once the store has been loaded from the server:

```
store.filterBy(function(record) {
    return record.get('Name').indexOf('EPIC') === 0;
});
```

The full App SDK documentation (including guides and links to the WSAPI documentation) can be found here:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/

I would also recommend upgrading to the most recent version of the SDK for app development (2.0rc2 as of this writing).

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/

Comment: well `contains` is dangerous for me, as I am looking for story names that start with 'EPIC'. I like to work on the latest SDK but since I am modifying and adding features to an app that uses the old sdk, I don't have much flexibility.

Comment: I updated the answer above in light of your new information.  Check out the filterBy method.